# Which WordPress template serves the header logo link?

Tags: wordpress, templates, header

I added WordPress to a static website in order to host my business blog via WordPress. I simply want the logo header atop the WordPress blog to link to my main site homepage rather than to the blog homepage.

Specifically, I want the header on all pages within this blog: http://matrixpremier.com/seo-blog/
to link here to: http://matrixpremier.com/.

I looked in every WordPress template and did not see any href link to the main blog page. Does anyone know which template manages the blog header logo, and what I should change in the code? I am using the "Gridbox" theme. I did not see what I'm looking for in header.php. Also, I am not a developer and only know basic HTML.

I searched extensively on forums for this. The closest answer was: 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37292/how-do-you-find-out-which-template-page-is-serving-the-current-page but none of the responses solved this for my situation. Some answers I didn't understand. The "What the File" plugin did not provide the answer. The Debug Bar seemed too complex and code heavy on the site. Also I do not find this in the code: php echo.

In this solution: [Detect which WordPress template is being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119916/detect-which-wordpress-template-is-being-used), I wan's sure where to add the get_post_meta tag to, and what to do next then to check the result.

And I think this solution: [Display which Wordpress template and template_part files are used to construct a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664668/display-which-wordpress-template-and-template-part-files-are-used-to-construct-a) is only going to tell me which template each blog page uses. That's not what I want to know. I want to know which template contains the header logo link, and I can't find it.

Thank you much in advance!

Comment: The first place you should look is the header.php file in your theme. Typically, your page template will call `get_header()` to include the header.php code. Your logo and the corresponding href link are likely there.

Comment: Thanks, Mastrianni. I did check header.php several times and no go. Cale's answer below appears to be the start of a solution. Beginning with changing my theme's general settings URL.

Answer (score 1):

**You're trying to fix this the wrong way**.

If you ask Google "Change WordPress Home URL", you'll find many good links - this one is very helpful: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL.

To answer the question you *asked*:
You need to understand WordPress themes, and that each theme can be very different.  A good place to start is by looking in `wp-content/themes` - and look at the theme you're using. It's probably in the file `header.php` - but the link is probably being generated by a WP function such as `get_site_url()` - and you **DO NOT** want to change that.

**The right way to solve the actual problem:**
Instead of altering your theme, change your **settings** to use the correct URL.  (Normally in the dashboard under "Settings" => "General" - there's two URLs you can enter, one for "WordPress" and one for "Site").

You'll even see this "tip" on that page:

> Enter the address here if you want your site home page to be different from your WordPress installation directory.

Which links to this page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: Thank you much, Cale, for redirecting my research. This certainly looks like the correct path but I ran into a hitch. The WordPress instructions tell me to change something in my index.php file that does not exist. It says: Change the line that says:
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
to the following, using your directory name for the WordPress core files:
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );.    But there is nothing similar to this in my index.php file. Any idea what I should do instead? Should I copy that code into an answer here?

Comment: Thanks again. To be clear: The **root directory** of my Hostgator account contains none of the files you mention. The **root directory** for this website is public_html and that contains the index.php file that I just copied to that location and in file editor that version is very long and without the require (dirname...). Nor does that public_html folder contain wp-config.php or wp-cron.php. Then there is the **root directory** of the WordPress blog I added in a folder called /public_html/seo-blog. This is only the root directory for the blog (contrary to instructions, I believe).

Comment: That index.php file look just as you describe. However, when I change that file to add /wordpress/ into the dirname, then when I login to the new location (which I think should be http://matrixpremier.com/seo-blog/wordpress/wp-admin/, the page gives this warning:

Comment: Warning: require(/home4/muzzy/public_html/seo-blog/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home4/muzzy/public_html/seo-blog/index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home4/muzzy/public_html/seo-blog/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in /home4/muzzy/public_html/seo-blog/index.php on line 17. I'm not sure which way to turn on this again. Any further insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: After a lot of additional trial and error attempts to get this to work, I called Hostgator. He clarified that changing the site address in WordPress General > Settings is the wrong way to go about what I am trying to do. And everytime I do that, it breaks the WordPress installation entirely. The reason that is the wrong way to go about this is: That would install WordPress over my entire already-existing website. Not my goal. I am adding this WordPress blog as a small segment within an existing static website, as I stated in the first sentence above.

Comment: This isn't resolved at all, and now I'm going to see if I can get help on either the WordPress forum or from the Gridbox theme's developer. Thanks for the efforts though.

Comment: Close this. I found another way to do it. Just delete the header logo. Then add new code into the header.php template.